# The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRangeList

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm building a range list by creating a  rangeString  . Is there a way to pass it into the getRangeList method ? See below

var rangeString= "a:a"+ "," +"b:b"
var rangelist =ss.getRangeList([rangeString])

I get this msg when i try to do so :

*The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRangeList*

Any help/suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: `[rangeString]` is a array. It should be `["a:a","b:b"]`

Comment: The thing is : I'm building the array in a loop mode. See precision below :

for (i=1;i<=lastColumn;i++)  {
   
   if (rangelist!=""){var rangelist = rangelist +","+valModif+":"+valModif}
   else {
    var rangelist = valModif+":"+valModif
        }

}

valModif can be (A:A or B:B or C;C etc)

Comment: [Edit] your question with code. Look into array methods like push. Use [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code. [Test formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) before posting questions.